# Import file and append to previously loaded file in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to make a shiny app, with which I can upload excel file sequentially. Each time I upload a file, it add to the previous loaded file (assuming they have the same format).

What I did was I defined a `df_all` as a empty dataframe. each time I click upload and choose a file, I did `bind_rows(df_all, df)`. But it did not work.

Can anyone help me figure what I did wrong?  I spent hours try all different things but unsuccessful.

```
# set working directory
setwd(my_working_directory)

ipak <- function(pkg){
    new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
    if (length(new.pkg)) 
        install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
    sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}

packages <- c('devtools', 'readxl',
              'shiny', 'DT')
ipak(packages)

## ui
##---------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(9, h2('Import Excel'), align='center')    
    ),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            #----------------------Upload Files-----------------
            conditionalPanel(
                condition= " input.tabs == 'Upload_Files' ",

                fileInput('file', 'Choose Excel file',
                          accept = c(".xlsx")
                )
            )        
        ),        
        #------------------------------Main Panel------------------------    
        mainPanel(            
            tabsetPanel(
                id = 'tabs',               
                tabPanel('Upload_Files',
                         fluidRow (
                             column(12, DT::dataTableOutput('data.table1') ) 
                         ) 
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
##--------------------server-----------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    df_all = data.frame()

    output$data.table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({

        # input$file will be NULL initially.

        req(input$file)
        inFile <- input$file

        if(is.null(inFile)) {
            return(NULL)
        }

        df=read_excel(inFile$datapath)
        df_all = bind_rows(df_all, df)
        return(df_all)
    })
}
runApp(shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server))
```

Comment: *"But it did not work"*. Can you provide details? R has hundreds of errors messages, it'd be much easier if we knew which one to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updating of `df_all` is flawed for two reasons:

1. When you reference `df_all` inside the reactive block, it takes the outer-reference (outside the reactive block) then assigns it to a `df_all` inside the block, never updating the one outside. In some contexts, this suggests the use of `<<-`, though I discourage that mindset as it leads towards problematic programming (side-effect should really be avoided if unnecessary). And ...
2. You should have the outer `df_all` be reactive.

Instead, try

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    df_all <- reactiveVal(NULL)

    output$data.table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        req(input$file)
        olddf <- isolate(df_all())
        if(is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
        df <- readr::read_excel(input$file$datapath)
        df <- dplyr::bind_rows(olddf, df)
        isolate(df_all(df))
        return(df)
    })
}
```

This should work assuming that all tables are similarly-structured. You might want to be a little more cautious in your row-binding via some pre-checks and such (confirm names in one present in the other, etc).

BTW: I use `isolate(...)` so that re-rendering the table does not double-trigger the `DT:renderDataTable`. That's not to say that the rendering cannot be responsive to something *else* making changes to `df_all`, but not self-imposed (circular) reactivity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works!   Sorry for one more question.  I also need a reactive dataframe that is generated from this process, so that I can use later in the app for data vis, in addition to just showing the data table.  How can I do that? @r2evans

Comment: I don't understand ... `df_all` is a reactive frame. Anything that depends on `df_all()` in any other block should be reactive to its changes. Is it not behaving as such?